# jarsigner with timestamp but the error responder's certificate not within the validity period

Tags: java, jarsigner

I have signed the jars with timestamp for the certificate that expires on jan-2017. I changed my system time to after jan-2017. 
When I run applet that downloads above jars, I get the error responder's certificate not within the validity period.
As per java documentation it says if the jarsigner uses timestamp it validates even after certificate expires. 
What could be the issue?

Update 1: If I disable internet, it works fine without error even after system date change to after jan-2017, but not when connected to internet. 
Why is it accessing internet to validate certificate?

Answer (score 1):

good anwser from [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3688374/holger) at [How to check if Java Web Start app will continue working after certificate expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046457/how-to-check-if-java-web-start-app-will-continue-working-after-certificate-expir)

> Reason and workaround
>
> Your exception stacktrace shows that the certificate revocation check
>   using OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol) has failed because of
>   the expiration of the OCSP responder's certificate at your test date
>   (not because of your certificate).
>
> To perform the test try to switch certificate revocation checks off in
>   the Java Control Panel.
>
> Also be sure that your certificate has not already been permanently
>   accepted (use "Restore security prompts" in the Java Control Panel).